# Factor a rank one operator on a Hilbert C*-module.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

Let $A \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_0)$ be a concrete $C^*$-algebra and $X$ be a right Hilbert A-module. For each $x,y \in X$ we have rank one operators
\begin{align}
\theta_{x,y}: X & \to X \\
 z & \mapsto x\langle y, z\rangle_A 
\end{align}
The set $\mathcal{K}_A(X):=\overline{\mathrm{span}\{\theta_{x,y} : x,y \in X\}}$ is well known to be a $C^*$ algebra.

> **Question:** Can I always find a representation of $\mathcal{K}_A(X)$ on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1$ such that for any $x \in X$ the map $\theta_{x,x}$, regarded as an element of $ \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_1)$, "factors trhough $\mathcal{H}_0$"? To be precise, can I always find an element $b_x \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_1, \mathcal{H}_0)$ such that $\theta_{x,x}=b_x^* b_x$?

I can't seem to find this in any of my usual references for Hilbert modules. It seems to be true for all the examples I've tried. For instance, for a usual Hilbert space regarded as a right Hilbert $\mathbb{C}$-module, we have $b_x=\langle x|$ so that $b_x^*$ is multiplication by $x$.

However, I can't quite prove it in general nor find a counterexample. I don't mind assuming that $X$ is full, but I am not sure this is needed. Also, it might be that this only works for a carefully chosen $\mathcal{H}_1$, but this is fine as I care for a "concrete" result rather than a necessarily abstract one.

Any reference or help to prove/disprove the claim will be much appreciated.

Comment: If both $H_0$ and $H_1$ are infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces, the answer is trivially yes. Just take $b_x=u\theta_{x, x}$, where $u:H_1→H_0$ is an isometry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ruy. I get $b_x^*b_x=\theta_{\theta_{x,x}(x),x}$. This can be fixed though: since $\theta_{x,x}$ is positive, letting $b_x:=u(\theta_{x,x})^{1/2}$ works. Also, I get why such $u$ exists when the cardinality of $H_1$ is less or equal that the one of $H_0$. But I don't quite see why such isometry exists if the cardinality of $H_1$ is strictly bigger than the cardinality of $H_0$?

Comment: Dear @Alonso, I did mean to write $\theta_{x,x}^{1/2}$ but I guess I forgot the square root.  Good you noticed!  Regarding your last question, the answer is no, and a counter-example is $A=X=H_0=\mathbb C$, $x=1$, and $H_1$ any Hilbert space with dimension bigger than 1.

Comment: @Ruy right! So I agree that the answer is trivial as long as $H_0$ and $H_1$ are Hilbert spaces such that the cardinality of $H_1$ is less or equal than the one of $H_0$. I am still wondering about whether my question can be answered true in general. In your example, $K_A(X)$ is again $\mathbb{C}$, whence $H_0=H_1$ and the answer is again yes.

Comment: The counter-examole I had in mind corresponds to representing $K_A(X)$ in some big Hilbert space, which obviously can be done.   So perhaps you should clarify what do you mean by $K_A(X)\subset B(H_1)$.

Comment: @Ruy I would like to know if I can always find a representation of $K_A(X)$ such that $\theta_{x,x}$ "factors through" $H_0$. This is what I meant in my post when I wrote [...] *it might be that this only works for a carefully chosen $H_1$, but this is fine as I care for a "concrete" result rather than a necessarily abstract one.* [...] I probably need to be more clear about this. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: I guess Zorngo has put our discussion to rest, right?

Comment: I agree. Thanks a lot for you input @Ruy. I actually also figured how to deal with this with your approach as well, I wrote it as a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\mathcal{H}_0$ define $\mathcal{H}_1 := X \otimes_{A} \mathcal{H}_0$, which is a Hilbert space carrying a representation of $\mathcal{K}(X)$ given by $T(x \otimes h) = (Tx) \otimes h$. Define $b_x$ to be the "creation" operator $b_x \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}_0,\mathcal{H}_1)$ satisfying $b_x(h) = x \otimes h$ and then $b_x^*$ is the corresponding "annihilation" operator  $b_x^*(y \otimes h)  = \pi((x \mid y)_A) h$, where $\pi$ is the representation of $A$ on $\mathcal{H}_0$. Then
$$
b_x b_x^* (y \otimes h) = x \otimes \pi((x \mid y)_A)h = x(x \mid y)_A \otimes h = \Theta_{x,x}(y) \otimes h.
$$
Of course there's some checking to be done to make sure everything is well-defined.

I should also mention that the representation of $\mathcal{K}(X)$ on $\mathcal{H}_1$ is faithful since $\pi$ is faithful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check the details later today but this is exactly what I've been looking for. Funny enough I never thought of using a creation operator even though I need this result for a "Fock space type" construction that I've been working on.

Comment: For further reference, I think one might also get away with this using what @Ruy suggested in the comments above. Indeed, suppose that we are given representations of $A$ and $K_A(X)$ on $H_0$ and $H_1$ respectively. Then, if the cardinality of $H_1$ is less or equal than the one of $H_0$, we are done by Ruy's isometry trick. Otherwise, we can represent $A$ in $H_0 \oplus H_1$ and now we can use the isometry trick again.